# radio button click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

There are some radio buttons inside my `asp.net` wizard control.

For better understanding Markup:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="WizardCreateDL" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" BackColor="#F7F6F3"
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="0.8em"
        Height="337px" Width="800px" OnNextButtonClick="WizardCreateDL_NextButtonClick"
        OnCancelButtonClick="WizardCreateDL_CancelButtonClick" OnPreviousButtonClick="WizardCreateDL_PreviousButtonClick"
        DisplaySideBar="False" BorderStyle="Solid" OnFinishButtonClick="WizardCreateDL_FinishButtonClick">
        <StepStyle BorderWidth="0px" />
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="stepCreateFolder" runat="server" Title="FolderOptions" >
                <div id="dvFolderOptions" runat="server" style="text-align: left; width: 45%; margin: auto; font-size:medium">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio" id="rdbCalendar" value="0" name="Cal" onclick="appendChild(this);" /><label for="rdbCalendr">Calendar</label></li><br />
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio" id="rdbTasks" value="0" name="Cal" onclick="appendChild(this);"  /><label for="rdbTasks">Tasks</label></li><br />
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio" id="rdbContacts" value="0" name="Cal" onclick="appendChild(this);"  /><label for="rdbContacts">Contacts</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
        <StartNavigationTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MoveNext"
                Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="1.3em" Text="Next" Visible="false" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="1.3em"
                Text="Finish" Visible="false" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnFinish_Click" />
        </StartNavigationTemplate>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

The js event:

```
function appendChild(crnt) {
            alert('hi');
            var parentLi = $(crnt).parents('li:first');
            if (parentLi.find('ul:first').length == 0) {
                var Container = $('<ul></ul>').append('<li><input type="radio" id="rdbEditor" value="0" onclick="secondLevelChild();" /><label for="rdbEditor">Editor</label></li><li><input type="radio" id="rdbReviewer" value="0" onclick="secondLevelChild();"  /><label for="rdbReviewer">Reviewer</label></li>')
                parentLi.html(Container);
            }
        }
```

i have been struggling to fire this event , tried also possible ways to do this like :

```
$(function () {
  $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_WizardCreateDL_dvFolderOptions').find('li').each(function   () {
        $(this).find('input:radio').click(function () {
            appendChild(this);
            alert('1+2+3');
        });
    });

});
```

but it is just not ready to fire, any help??

Comment: are you getting any error message or something???

Comment: Try to use this to get correct client id for div `$('[id$=dvFolderOptions]').find('li')`

Comment: there is an error that is coming : 
Error: TypeError: window.opener.reload is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try you code, seems like "appendChild" is a built in js function , giving error for me, so when i changes its name to some thing else like "appendChild1" its worked fine, give it a try...

Comment: I think you are right @anilDbut since i am getting this error  
TypeError: window.opener.reload is not a function. I am not able to see the reflection of changes in my code. Can you suggest something to resolve this error.

Comment: so after changing function name, you event is fired and now you are getting following "Error: TypeError: window.opener.reload is not a function " error ?

Comment: no the error was already present, might be due to this error the functions were not firing . But to check that i have to remove the error .

Comment: so it is some other js code that errors out, i need that, could you please add that to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code

```
$('#<%=dvFolderOptions.ClientID %> li input:radio').click(function()
{
appendChild(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you check what is the HTML rendered using view source or firebug? So we can change selector accordingly

Comment: I have a popup that is opened before this step in the wizard... that is giving an error. I have posted the error in my comments...

Comment: window.opener is basically your parent page which opens popup. Where you are calling window.opener.reload? in popup?

Comment: there are three steps in the wizard, So the first step open a popup to search something and enter pass on the data to parent page. So to close the popup I am using window.opener.reload.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function name appendChild to any other name becoz appendChild is already present in javascript

change 
**This**

```
function appendChild(crnt) {
    // code goes here
}
```

**To**

```
function appendMyChild(crnt) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: I  have tried that too @rajesh, but my previous error is not changing the scenario for me.

Comment: @ankur can you make fiddle of your html output

Comment: there is lot of code behind code that is involved so i think fiddle won't help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[id$=dvFolderOptions]').delegate('li input:radio', 'click', function(){ 
            appendChild(this);
            alert('1+2+3');
        });
```

Comment: based on error message you posted in your comment, you have problem with other js functions also. Please fix them first

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#<%=dvFolderOptions.ClientID %>').find('li').each(function () {
```

instead of

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_WizardCreateDL_dvFolderOptions').find('li').each(function   () {
```

I just tested and it works!